# Oracle: join of two fast, non-correlated queries causing slow query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Why is the join of two fast, simple queries taking such a long time to run?

How can I force the sub-query to be run only once?

### The problem

I have a query that joins on a *non-correlated* subquery (I have simplified this example down somewhat for the sake of illustration) that takes 1684 seconds to return 3450 rows of data.

However, the subquery, when run on it's own, runs in <2 seconds, and if I remove the sub-query, the overall query runs in less than 5 seconds.

If they are non-correllated, the subquery should only be running once, for a total execution time of ~8-9 seconds, no?

How can I force the subquery to only run once and cache the result?

### The queries themselves:

- The full query with subquery (3450 rows in 1684 seconds (28 minutes))

  ```
  SELECT
                    table_1.a, 
                    table_3.b, 
                    table_4.c, 
                    subquery_result.c

  FROM              table_1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_2 on (table_2.x = table_1.y)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_3 on (table_3.x = table_2.y)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_4 on (table_4.x = table_2.z)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_5 on (table_5.x = table_4.y)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 

                    (
                      SELECT 
                                        view_1.a, 
                                        view_2.b, 
                                        resultOfLongCaseStatement c

                      FROM              view_1 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN   view_2 on (view_1.x = view_2.y)
                    ) subquery_result   on (table_1.x = subquery_result.b)

  WHERE             table_3.val = 'SOMEVAL'
  AND               table_2.val in ('VAL', 'OTHERVAL')
  AND               table_5.val is not null
  AND               subquery_result.a not in ('blah', 'blahh');
  ```
- subquery on it's own (returns 3812 rows in <2 seconds)

  ```
  SELECT 
                    view_1.a, 
                    view_2.b, 
                    resultOfLongCaseStatement

  FROM              view_1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   view_2 on (view_1.x = view_2.y)
  ```
- overall query without subquery (returns 3504 rows in 4.4 seconds):

  ```
  SELECT
                    table_1.a, 
                    table_3.b, 
                    table_4.c, 
                    --subquery_result.c

  FROM              table_1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_2 on (table_2.x = table_1.y)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_3 on (table_3.x = table_2.y)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_4 on (table_4.x = table_2.z)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_5 on (table_5.x = table_4.y)

  WHERE             table_3.val = 'SOMEVAL'
  AND               table_2.val in ('VAL', 'OTHERVAL')
  AND               table_5.val is not null
  AND               subquery_result.a not in ('blah', 'blahh');
  ```
- entire query rewritten with a 'with' clause - same performance as running the above overall query:

  ```
  WITH subquery_result as 
                  (
                      SELECT 
                                        view_1.a, 
                                        view_2.b, 
                                        resultOfLongCaseStatement c

                      FROM              view_1 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN   view_2 on (view_1.x = view_2.y)
                  )

  SELECT
                    table_1.a, 
                    table_3.b, 
                    table_4.c, 
                    subquery_result.c

  FROM              table_1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_2 on (table_2.x = table_1.y)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_3 on (table_3.x = table_2.y)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_4 on (table_4.x = table_2.z)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   table_5 on (table_5.x = table_4.y)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   subquery_result   on (table_1.x = subquery_result.b)

  WHERE             table_3.val = 'SOMEVAL'
  AND               table_2.val in ('VAL', 'OTHERVAL')
  AND               table_5.val is not null
  AND               subquery_result.a not in ('blah', 'blahh');
  ```

Why does the join of a 2 and 5 second query cause a 23 minute query time?

Is the subquery running once for every row the overall query is producing? How can I force it not to do this?

### What I've tried:

- Rewriting the subquery as a 'with' statement - the execution time is still close to 28 minutes.
- As an experiment, to make sure the join wasn't the issue, I Tried putting the output of the subquery into a table and joining on that: This makes the query run in just a few seconds - but I can't use this approach to solve my problem
- Rewriting the subqueries slightly and running them for the first time, in case the fast results I'm seeing are just cached - the execution times for the subquery and the overall query without the subquery are still the same - many hundreds of times faster than both joined together.

Comment: A LEFT JOIN with a right side table condition in the WHERE clause returns regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: @jarlh - you are right there - I just wanted to change as little as possible in my example. The subquery would still be non-correllated regardless of the join used though, no? Do you think removing the where conditions on the right side of the join would affect performance significantly?

Comment: @jarlh ... ok if I remove all where clauses it runs in like 14 seconds......... huh? why?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that one of the column in the tables I was querying (say, table_2.val was brand new - it had no index and the optimizer had 0 statistics on the column.

This was not an issue when SELECTing that column - but when I included the column in the WHERE clause, the optimizer apparently struggled greatly - as it appeared to be running the subquery as if it was correlated (once per result in the overall query) - even though table_2 is not mentioned or referred to anywhere in the subquery.

Quick solution was: comment out each predicate in the where clause one at at a time and see which one caused massive performance improvements.

I believe (but have not tested) that updating statistics on my 'table_2' would also solve this problem longer term.